# How to update table2 from table1, into corresponding entry in table2?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, union

I want to count the occurrences of banks in different tables, and update in corresponding columns of FinalTable.

BankTable:

```
  BankName  ErrorCode
    SBI         200
    ICICI       200
    SBI         400
    SBI         500
    SBI         503
```

ATMTable:

```
BankName    ErrorCode
ICICI       200
ICICI       400
ICICI       400
SBI         500
SBI         503
```

MitraTable:

```
BankName    ErrorCode
ICICI        200
ICICI        200
SBI          400
SBI          500
SBI          503
PNB          501
```

FinalTable:

```
BankName    BankCount   ATMCount    MitraCount  TotalCount
ICICI            1         3           2          6
SBI              4         2           3          9
PNB              0         0           1          1
```

I want to count the occurances of different banks and set the values in FinalTable.

Comment: Include other RDBMS tags as well... make it a mystry

Comment: I removed the incompatible database tags.  Please tag questions only with the database you are actually using.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `UNION ALL` together with conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT BankName,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN src = 'Bank' THEN 1 END) AS BankCount,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN src = 'ATM' THEN 1 END) AS ATMCount,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN src = 'Mitra' THEN 1 END) AS MitraCount,
       COUNT(*) AS TotalCount

FROM (
   SELECT BankName, 'Bank' AS src 
   FROM BankTable

   UNION ALL 

   SELECT BankName, 'ATM' AS src
   FROM ATMTable

   UNION ALL

   SELECT BankName, 'Mitra' AS src
   FROM MitraTable) AS t
GROUP BY BankName
```

Field `src` is used to return the source table to the outer query consuming the results of the `UNION ALL` operations. Using this field we can perform *conditional aggregation* in order to count the occurence of each bank in each of the source tables.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT BankName, 
       SUM(BankCount) AS BankCount, 
       SUM(ATMCount) AS ATMCount, 
       SUM(MitraCount) AS MitraCount, 
       SUM(BankCount + ATMCount + MitraCount) AS TotalCount 
FROM (SELECT BankName, 
             COUNT(ErrorCode) AS BankCount, 
             0 AS ATMCount, 
             0 AS MitraCount 
      FROM BankTable 
      GROUP BY BankName 
     UNION 
      SELECT BankName, 
             0 AS BankCount, 
             COUNT(ErrorCode) AS ATMCount, 
             0 AS MitraCount 
      FROM ATMTable 
      GROUP BY BankName 
     UNION 
      SELECT BankName, 
             0 AS BankCount, 
             0 AS ATMCount, 
             COUNT(ErrorCode) AS MitraCount 
      FROM MitraTable 
      GROUP BY BankName
    ) AS A
GROUP BY BankName;
```